# Does jBehave work with Robolectric?

Tags: android, bdd, robotium, robolectric, jbehave

I'd like to use Behavior Driven Development (BDD) to develop an Android app.  I'm thinking of using jBehave with Robolectric.  Someone wrote about using [jBehave with Robotium](http://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/knowledge/testing-android-apps-with-robotium-and-jbehave/) but does anyone know if Robolectric can be used instead of Robotium with jBehave?

Any known issues?

Comment: I was always thinking that Robolectric is used for unit tests and jBehave is for acceptance tests. But maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

`Robotium` is a tool for unit/acceptance testing on emulator or real device, `Robolectric` is library to unit test android code on desktop jvm. I think it would be possible to pair `jBehave` with `Robolectric` but again as for me it would be something that doesn't fit well.

As example simple behaviour test on android:

```
Activity A with list, user press item at position 2, user see Activity B details 
for for the second object in the list.
```

Test on `Robotium` will:

- press on activity A list item
- check that activity B shown with UI that represents details

Tests with `Robolectric` are smaller:

- you could check that pressing item on A will fire Intent for launching new activity with specified details
- another test would check that B will show details

So you could try with `jBehave` *map* **"see item details"** to `Robolectric` **“Intent fired”** but this check is misleading because there so many things could happen from firing Intent to showing Activity with details. 
You could in `Robolectric` also try to fire activity and check details but this level of mocking is too much for BDD which suppose to have as less mocking as possible.

Comment: Thanks @EugenMartynov, I think your comment to my question was a nice summary: Robolectric is used for unit tests and jBehave is for acceptance tests. As a product manager, I loved the idea of combining the two because I thought it would produce a higher-quality product.

Comment: Also, @EugenMartynov can you review your answer for typos and I'll gladly accept it as the answer.  I had trouble reading the Activity block because I think there are some typos.